# Javascript's replace for each word

Tags: javascript

I have a text box and, when the user hits space, I want each individual word to have a # prepended.

So far the code I have is:

```
  tagsNow = document.getElementById("tags").value;
  tagsChanged = tagsNow.replace(/(w+)/, "#$1");
  document.getElementById("tags").value = tagsChanged;
```

It partly works, as the # is prepended on the first time (`word` becomes `#word`).

However, if another word is typed, the # is just added right at the start of the text box, and it also adds another # if the user types their own #.

How could I solve these two problems?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, tags are separated with a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function tagify(str){
  return str.replace(/([^#]+?)(\s+|\b)/g, function(mat, grp1, grp2, at, src){
    return src[at-1] == "#" ? mat : "#" + mat;
  });
}

tagify("japan travel"); // "#japan #travel"
tagify("#torii bird");  // "#torii #bird"
tagify("C C#");         // "#C #C#"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine something like this would work:

```
tagsChanged = tagsNow.replace(/(^| )(?=!#)/g,"$1#");
```

This basically searches for spaces (and the start of the string) that don't have a `#` after them, and inserts that `#`.

Comment: Thank you, but Chrome's output gives the error: `Invalid regular expression: /(^| )(?>!#)/: Invalid group`

Comment: My mistake, it should be `(?=!` instead of `(?>!`

Comment: I've made this change, and although the error is gone, no change is made at all to the text in the text box. Any ideas? Thanks.